# Showing that `newtype T a = T (a -> Int)` is a Type Constructor that is Not a Functor

Tags: haskell, category-theory

It's been claimed that `newtype T a = T (a -> Int)` is a type constructor that is not a functor (but is a contravariant functor). How so? Or what is the contravariant functor (whence I assume it will be obvious why this can't be made a normal functor)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
newtype T a = T (a -> Int)
```

let's try to build the `Contravariant` instance for this datatype.

Here's the typeclass in question:

```
class Contravariant f where
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

Basically, `contramap` is akin to `fmap`, but instead of lifting a function `a -> b` to `f a -> f b`, it lifts it to `f b -> f a`.

Let's begin writing the instance...

```
instance Contravariant T where
  contramap g (T f) = ?
```

Before we fill in the `?`, let's think about what the types of `g` and `f` are:

```
g :: a -> b
f :: b -> Int
```

And for clarity, we might as well mention that

```
f a ~ T (a -> Int)
f b ~ T (b -> Int)
```

So we can fill in the `?` as follows:

```
instance Contravariant T where
  contramap g (T f) = T (f . g)
```

To be super pedantic, you might rename `g` as `aToB`, and `f` as `bToInt`.

```
instance Contravariant T where
  contramap aToB (T bToInt) = T (bToInt . aToB)
```

The reason you can write a `Contravariant` instance for `T a` boils down to the fact that `a` is in contravariant position in `T (a -> Int)`. The best way to convince yourself that `T a` isn't a `Functor` is to try (and fail) to write the `Functor` instance yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that T is a functor. Then we have

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> T a -> T b
```

Now, let's try implementing it.

```
instance Functor T where
  fmap f (T g) = T $ \x -> _y
```

Clearly we start with something like this, and combine the values `f`, `g`, and `x` somehow to compute a value for `y` that's of the right type. How can we do that? Well, notice I've called it `_y`, which tells GHC I need some help figuring out what to put there. What does GHC have to say?

```
<interactive>:7:28: error:
    • Found hole: _y :: Int
      Or perhaps ‘_y’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    • In the expression: _y
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘\ x -> _y’
      In the expression: T $ \ x -> _y
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: b (bound at <interactive>:7:23)
        g :: a -> Int (bound at <interactive>:7:13)
        f :: a -> b (bound at <interactive>:7:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> T a -> T b (bound at <interactive>:7:3)
```

So now we're clear about the types of everything relevant, right? We need to return an `Int` somehow, and what we have to build it out of are:

```
        x :: b
        g :: a -> Int
        f :: a -> b
```

Well, okay, the only thing we have that can possibly create an `Int` is `g`, so let's fill that in, leaving `g`'s argument blank to ask GHC for more help:

```
instance Functor T where
  fmap f (T g) = T $ \x -> g _y

<interactive>:7:31: error:
    • Found hole: _y :: a
      Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> T a -> T b
               at <interactive>:7:3
      Or perhaps ‘_y’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    • In the first argument of ‘g’, namely ‘(_y)’
      In the expression: g (_y)
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘\ x -> g (_y)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: b (bound at <interactive>:7:23)
        g :: a -> Int (bound at <interactive>:7:13)
        f :: a -> b (bound at <interactive>:7:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> T a -> T b (bound at <interactive>:7:3)
```

Okay, we could have predicted this ourselves: to call `g`, we need a value of type `a` from somewhere. But we don't have any values of type `a` in scope, and we don't have any functions that return a value of type `a` either! We're stuck: it's impossible to produce a value of the type we want now, even though at every step we did the only possible thing: there's nothing we could back up and try differently.

Why did this happen? Because if I give you a function of type `a -> Int` and say "but by the way, here's a function from `a -> b`, please give me back a function from `b -> Int` instead", you can't actually *use* the function from `a -> b`, because nobody ever gives you any `a`s to call it on! If I had given you a function from `b -> a` instead, that would be quite helpful, right? You could produce a function from `b -> Int` then, by first calling the `b -> a` function to get an `a`, and then calling the original `a -> Int` function to get out the desired `Int`.

And that's what a contravariant functor is about: we reverse the arrow in the function passed to `fmap`, so it can fmap over things you "need" (function arguments) instead of things you "have" (concrete values, return values of functions, etc).

---

Aside: I claimed earlier that we had done "the only possible thing" at each step, which was a bit of a fib. We can't build an `Int` out of `f`, `g`, and `x`, but of course we can make up all sorts of numbers out of the air. We don't know anything about the type `b`, so we can't get an `Int` that's derived from it in some way, but we could just say "let's always return zero", and this technically satisfies the type checker:

```
instance Functor T where
  fmap f (T g) = T $ const 0
```

Obviously this looks quite wrong, since it seems like `f` and `g` ought to be pretty important and we're ignoring them! But it type-checks, so we're okay, right?

No, this violates one of the Functor laws:

```
fmap id = id
```

We can prove this easily enough:

```
fmap id (T $ const 5) = (T $ const 0) /= (T $ const 5)
```

And now we really *have* tried everything: the only way we have to build an `Int` without using our `b` type at all is to make it up out of nothing, and all such uses will be isomorphic to using `const`, which will violate the Functor laws.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another bit of perspective. As liminalisht showed, `T` is `Contravariant`. What can we tell about types that are both covariant and contravariant?

```
import Data.Void


change1, change1', change2 :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => f a -> f b
change1 = contramap (const ()) . fmap (const ())
change1' = (() >$) . (() <$)
change2 = fmap absurd . contramap absurd
```

The first two implementations are basically the same (`change1'` being an optimization of `change1`); each of them uses the fact that `()` is a "terminal object" of **Hask**. `change2` instead uses the fact that `Void` is an "initial object".

Each of these functions replaces all the `a`s in `f a` with `b`s without knowing anything whatsoever about `a`, `b`, or the relationship between them, leaving everything else the same. It should probably be clear that this means `f a` doesn't really depend on `a`. That is, `f`'s parameter must be phantom. That is *not* the case for `T`, so it can't also be covariant.